# When I call a component in Angular it doesn't appears, and the home component still appears even when the endpoint changes

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-routing

I've created a "student" component and when I called it it doesn't appears in the endpoint where it should be located! instead, the home component still appears even in the student endpoint (/student)

[image]
[image]

### Student component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
<p>student works!</p>
```

### app.routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './components/student/student.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'student', component: StudentComponent },];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

### app.component.html

```html
<h1>Grade Management</h1>
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'GradeManagement_FrontEnd';
}
```

### app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StudentComponent } from './components/student/student.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StudentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Could you provide as well `app.component.html` ?

Comment: can you add a stackblitz example here.

Comment: @Wandrille I've just added it, can you check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I've fixed the problem by adding the following in `app.component.html`.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the content of your app.component.html

Indeed, when you start your application it's the index.html which is loaded and it should contains "app-root" tag (file root of project). In practice your app.component.html should contain "router-outlet" tag to permit the routing

Comment: I've just added it, can you check again